# JavaScript - Accessing a child variable in a parent class

Tags: javascript, class, variables, inheritance, constructor

In JavasScript, is it possible to define a variable in a child class, then access it in a parent class? I imagine the child class would look something like this:

```
export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        this.path = 'register';
    }
}
```

A use-case scenario is an HTTP service class as the parent that contains general, reusable methods and a child class that defines the exact route that will be accessed. Assuming it's possible, how could I then access `this.path` in the parent class?

Comment: Conceptually that does not really make sense; how is the Parent supposed to know that a subclass has a particular property? How would a "Mammal" know that it has an "udder"?  That said, the parent class methods can simply attempt to refer to the property added by the child class, probably with checks to make sure the property is actually there.

Comment: This doesn't make sense from an object oriented standpoint. I will explain this with the old adage that a square is a rectangle but a rectangle is not a square. A child of a class is that class but that class does not end up being that child and thus cannot access its variables.

Comment: This isn't possible from a conceptual stand point. `ChildClass` has everything included in `ParentClass` in addition to anything it defines. The `ParentClass` doesn't know what `ChildClass` defines. `ChildClass` can access things from `ParentClass` because it is a type of `ParentClass`. Now with JavaScript, you could probably set up a system where this is possible using references and stuff; but, that's going to be extremely weird and probably horrifically bad practice.

Comment: A use-case scenario is an HTTP service class as the parent that contains general, reusable methods and a child class that defines the exact route that will be accessed. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: For that, you just need simple inheritance, which you're already doing.

Comment: But it's not working. `the parent class methods can simply attempt to refer to the property added by the child class, probably with checks to make sure the property is actually there.` Can someone show me an example of how to do this? I must be missing something basic here.

Comment: You need to make the call from the child class, not the parent class. I'm not sure how you're expecting to do the reverse.

Comment: In PHP (unless I'm losing my mind), I can construct a variable in a child class, extend a parent class, and the extended methods can then refer to the variable defined in the child class. Thus it's not necessary to call the methods in the child class. It makes for ultra slim code. I guess I assumed this was possible in JavaScript as well. Thanks, everyone, for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, it just works.

As mentioned in the comments, it doesn't necessarily make sense to design your classes like this, since the actual class of the object might not be that child class.

```js
class ParentClass {
  printPath() {
    console.log(this.path);
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.path = 'register';
  }
}

var c = new ChildClass();
c.printPath();
var p = new ParentClass();
p.printPath();
```

Comment: The line `super();` was what I was missing. Now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem of accessing the property in the parent, it's necessary just to get the child class to compile in the first place.

Comment: Didn't you get a console error saying that a child class constructor has to use `super()` before it can access `this`?

Comment: It wasn't compiling, and I assumed this had something to do with defining a variable in a child. I think I may have seen that error, but I didn't make the connection.